# How can I binding the SelectedItems property of a DataGrid in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

Well, I am using MVVM Light and I have tried the solution to pass as parameter the selectedItems of the datagrid in the event selectionChanged. So I can get the selecteditems and I can update my variable in the view model.

In a first moment, it is a good solution. The problem is that if I set in my view model the SelectedIndex property to -1 to deselect all or set to null the SelectedItem property, the event selectionChanged is not fired. I guess that really is it good, because why the view will notify to the view model the change of a property that is changed in a first moment in the view model? This does not create cycles, but then I need to clear my SelectedItems propery in my view model manually and notifiy and rise my event OnSelectionChanged to another view models changes in many parts of my code.

I would like to know how can I force to rise the selectionChagend event when I change the property in my view model. Perhaps the solution could be a attached property instead of using the event selectionChanged.

Which alternatives do I have?

Thank you.

Comment: try two way binding mode ie `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use RaisePropertyChanged in the setter  of the selected item.

```
private T _selectedItem;
public T SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        if(value != _selectedItem)
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
}
```

Or take a look at this one:
[INotifyPropertyChanged Is Obsolete](http://www.codemag.com/article/0907101)
and this one:
[Data Binding without INotifyPropertyChanged](http://updatecontrols.net/cs/)

**EDIT:**
Since 4.6 there's a more beautiful way:

```
private T _selectedItem;
public T SelectedItem
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedItem;
    }
    set
    {
        if(value != _selectedItem)
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
```

[CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) is for passing the Name of the calling member implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but it is how I have, but it does not work. The odd thing is that if I set in the view model Selectedindex to -1 the propery SelectedItem is set to null, so it seems that the view set the SelectedItem, but the event is not rise.

Comment: Could you post the related code from your _Model_, _View_ and _ViewModel_?